# WCF vs Winsock (15 chars)

Tags: c#, wcf

Скажите WCF внутри использует Winsock? Просто интересно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использует частично.

Все клиентские каналы построены поверх Winsock.

Серверные HTTP-каналы используют драйвер HTTP.SYS, который *не* использует Winsock (он напрямую использует сетевой стек ядра).

Серверные Net.Tcp-каналы *могут* использовать Winsock, если настройка postSharingEnabled выключена. В режиме же совместного использования порта сетевая часть делегируется отдельной службе, приложение же напрямую Winsock не использует.